# Does the underscore symbol ignore or check for nullity in a switch statement in Swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, optional-binding

I have a switch statement in Swift like this:

```
switch tuple {
    case (let someObject, let current, nil):
        return true

    // Other cases...
}
```

The tuple is of type `(SomeObject?, SomeObject, SomeObject?)`, and what I'm saying in English is: *Match the case where the first two elements are **not** nil, while the third (an Optional) **is** nil.*

Xcode 7 is telling me that since I didn't use the bindings `someObject` and `current`, I should replace it with an underscore. But if I replaced the first element in the tuple with an underscore, wouldn't it also match the cases where the first element is nil, because `_` means the compiler ignores the value? *I have a separate case for situations where the first element is nil.*

For the record, it looks like my code still works as I expect it to, but I want to be sure and I can't find any documentation on this anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The underscore matches any value (nil or non-nil), but that is also
the case for your pattern:

```
case (let someObject, let current, nil):
```

where the first `let someObject` matches any value (nil or non-nil). So this does actually not work as you intended.

The optional type is defined as an enumeration:

```
enum Optional<T> : ... {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    // ....
}
```

and `nil` is the same as `Optional.None`.
Therefore you can use

```
case (.Some, _, nil):
// Alternatively: 
case (.Some, _, .None):
```

to match the case where the first element is not nil and the last
element is nil. The middle element of `(SomeObject?, SomeObject, SomeObject?)` is not an optional so it cannot be nil.

As of **Swift 2 / Xcode 7,** the `x?` pattern can be used as a synonym
for `.Some(x)`, in your case

```
case (_?, _, nil):
```

matches the case where the first element is not nil and the last element is nil.